# jquery not registering one of my radio buttons as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a radio button selection that jquery is able to loop through them and read the values for each one just fine, but jquery can only detect when one of them has been selected. When selecting the other one, jquery just ignores it and tells me none have been selected.

jquery:

```
           $('[name="banner_type"]').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
               if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    valid = $(this).val();
                   return valid;
               } else if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
                   valid = false;
               }
            });
```

html:

```
<input type="radio" id="upload" name="banner_type" value="upload" />
<input type="radio" id="html" name="banner_type" value="html" />
```

"upload" is being ignored by jquery, "html" is not

Comment: You don't need `else if` `else` is enough!

Comment: **Tip:** You can use `this.value` & `this.checked` instead of `$(this).is(':checked')` & `$(this).val()`

Comment: Is that code within a click or change event handler?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Im doing it this way:

```
valid=false;
$('[name="banner_type"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
        valid = $(this).val();
});
```

So each time You check for radio being checked, valid value is renewed.

here's fiddle for You. Function "check" checks validity, returning false if none is selected.
http://jsfiddle.net/CLaDG/

Comment: It worked! I am certainly not seeing how this fixes the problem I am having of jquery not seeing "upload" as checked, but I tried it for simplicity sake and it works as well! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, translating Your code into human-readable pseudo-code would be:
for each radio options, do {
check if current radio is checked, if it is return value and return. If not, also - return value and return
}
so you were returning first value breaking the loop. Also - unchecked radio has value equal to false, and checked - to its attribute value :-)

Answer (score 0):

The else part is setting value for valid but not returning it. Also the value is always false for second radio button. Try this:

```
$('[name="banner_type"]').each(function() {
   console.log($(this).val());
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      valid = $(this).val();
      return valid;
   } else if(!$(this).is(':checked')) {
      valid = $(this).val();
      return valid;
   }
});
```

This can be written shorter and better but right now I am just fixing the issue I see.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to make sure both are not checked before returning false. Your method would only be checking the first radio button no matter the outcome. This is why I had the return valid; outside the loop and not in the false condition.

Comment: These are radio buttons with same name "banner_type". They both can  never be checked at the same time. That's basic core radio button functionality.

Answer (score 0):

not sure which version of jQuery you are on, but try using jQuery.prop as well as delegated event on the container might be cleaner, such as:

```
$('.your-radios-container').on('change','[name="banner_type"]',function(){
    valid = $(this).prop('checked');
});
```

I have forked your fiddle to show you how it could work:

http://jsfiddle.net/AcMBR/2/

Comment: I am using version 1.7.2 so the .prop() function doesnt work for me.